# PHP- Error with SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC & sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

This code I am using to download result from sql server query  in excel . 
Connection & query works fine and I have already installed sqlsrv extensions properly.
But still I am getting error like these

> "Use of undefined constant SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC - assumed
>    SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC'"
>   "**Warning**:  sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long"

I think the problem is with `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  $serverName = "********"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"****", "UID"=>"***", "PWD"=>"*****");
$connect = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

  // filename for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  $query="select * from business_partners ORDER BY 1 desc";

  $result = sqlsrv_query($connect, $query) or die('A error occured: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
  while(false !== ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))) 
  {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }**strong text**
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
  exit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no explanation why the constant wouldn't be defined while the extension is clearly loaded, but you should be able to circumvent the problem by defining it yourself.

[`SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` has the value 2](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#sqlsrv/core_sqlsrv.h), so you should just add this somewhere, at best in a file you include always:

```
if ( !defined( 'SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC' ) )
  define( 'SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC', 2 );
```

The `if ( !defined() )` clause makes sure that your code doesn't break later, when the actual problem is fixed and the constant suddenly reappears.

Alternatively, if you only use it once in the file and it isn't really worth defining the constant (except for readability) you can just use the actual value as a parameter:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, 2 ); // 2 = SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC
```

Comment: I tried 
 while(false !== ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))) it worked .. but i dont need numerical values. 
Extension I am using php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll .

Comment: Did you get the same `undefined constant ` message for that?

Comment: no.  I dont know whats the issue with SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Try removing the complete constant, and maybe the adjacent characters and type them again (don't copy and paste them). It is quite possible that it's just an invisible utf8-character that you copied accidentally somewhere

Comment: I installed fresh "php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll"  and replaced with old one . I dont know how .. but that worked . 
Anyway Thanks Gerald